# How udi dahan domainevents class work?

Tags: c#, architecture, delegates, domain-driven-design

Udi Dahan DomainEvent class look like this:

```
namespace Udi.DomainEvent
{
    public static class DomainEvent
    {
        private static List<Delegate> Actions;
        public static IDisposable Register<T>(Action<T> callback)
        {
            Actions.Add(callback);
            return new DomainEventRegistrationRemover(() => Actions.Remove(callback));
        }

        private sealed class DomainEventRegistrationRemover : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly Action _callOnDispose;

            public DomainEventRegistrationRemover(Action callTo)
            {
                _callOnDispose = callTo;
            }
            public void Dispose()
            {
                _callOnDispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't understand How `Actions<T>.Remove()` function call while invoking `Actions` delegate ?
Why `Register<T>()` method return `IDisposable` type?

Answer (score 1):

The list of actions is so that the `DomainEvent` class knows what to execute as a callback for each registration. The `IDisposable` is returned so that the user can unregister their callback by disposing of this value.

I suspect the reason this is done is so you can register and unregister an anonymous delegate, otherwise you'll have to keep a reference to the action and pass it in when you are unregistering.

Usage:

```
var registration = domainEvent.Register(() => Console.WriteLine("I am registered")); 
// do stuff

// domainEvent may call callback while we are doing work.

// unregister, domainEvent can't call callback anymore.
registration.Dispose();
```

Comment: When actually `Actions.Remove(callback)` get called ?

Comment: when you call `registration.Dispose()`